# Copy cell value using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does PostgreSQL have a copy function ?

My data has a ditto sign for the values of few variables if they are same as above entry. 
In the case below, is it possible to copy the value for Year from the previous row if the id value matches

Have

```
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
| Year | Cost | Value | Col1       | id  |
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
| 2014 | 12   | 67    | Natural    | 156 |
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
| "    | 23   | 45    | Natural    | 156 |
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
```

Need

```
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
| Year | Cost | Value | Col1       | id  |
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
| 2014 | 12   | 67    | Natural    | 156 |
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
| 2014 | 23   | 45    | Natural    | 156 |
+------+------+-------+------------+-----+
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f3043/1

Comment: Rows in a relational database are not sorted. So there is - without using an `order by` - no such thing as the "previous row" or the "above entry". Which column (not "cell") in your table defines the "order" of the rows? I do not see an obvious choice.

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: The "id" column defines the order of the rows. I am getting a lot of missing values if I try to query based on the year, since the query only take into account " sign

Comment: The two rows have the same value for `ID` so the order of them is undefined even if using `order by id`

Answer (score 0):

smth like:

```
update t
set "Year" = p.y
from (
select *,lag("Year") over (order by id) from t
)
where "Year" is null;
```

not tested (build fiddle [somewhere](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) to let people test your data and code) - use with transaction